# Сохранение значения переменной String

Tags: java, android, строки, android-shared-preferences

В моём приложении на андроид есть две активити,в первой я использую radiogroup,при выборе radiobutton она передаёт свой id в виде переменной string на вторую активити и сохраняет положение isChecked,это работает хорошо,но на второй активити я пытаюсь сохранить переданную с первой активити имя кнопки,н о при закрытии и открытии приложения переменная String не сохраняется(открывается приложение с Activity 2,но там где должно отображатся сохранённое имя string просто пусто(для отслеживания я поставил на кнопку отображение имени String,при выборе различных radiobutton она отображает правильные имена,но при запуске оно всегда arb,как будто оно не сохраняет последнее значение)
Activity 1:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.menu); 
 intent = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

LoadCheckPreferences();

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(rad);
}

OnCheckedChangeListener rad = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

but = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
int checkedIndex = radioGroup.indexOfChild(but);

SaveCheckPreferences("save_key", checkedIndex);

name =getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkedId);
intent.putExtra("sample_pack",name);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
            }
        };

    private void SaveCheckPreferences(String key, int value) {
pref = getSharedPreferences("save_check", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt(key, value);
editor.apply();
    }

    private void LoadCheckPreferences() {
pref = getSharedPreferences("save_check", MODE_PRIVATE);
int savedRadioIndex = pref.getInt("save_key", 0);
but = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
but.setChecked(true);}
}
```

Activity 2:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
button();
packName = getIntent().getStringExtra("sample_pack");
SavePackPreferences("save_pack",packName);
if(packName==null){
LoadPackPreferences();}
if(packName!=null){
for (int s1=0;s1<12;s1++){
samp[s1]=getResources().getIdentifier(packName+s1, "raw", getPackageName());
soundId[s1]=mSound.load(MainActivity.this,samp[s1],0);}}}

public void SavePackPreferences(String key, String value){
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e= prefs.edit();
        e.putString(key,value);
        e.apply();
    }

    public void LoadPackPreferences(){
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        packName=prefs.getString("save_pack", "arb"));
    }
```

Comment: А каким образом Вы при повторном открытии приложения вызываете Activity 2?

Comment: Тоже при нажатии на кнопку из RadioGroup?

Comment: Нет,просто приложение открывается с активити2,а активити1 идёт как меню,но вызывается при необходимости...хотел расписать подробнее,что бы легче представлять задуманную идею,но это лишь приводит к побочным вопросам которые к сути не особо имеют отношения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно, при новом открытии приложения у вас в `Activity 2` снова вызывается метод `onCreate` и в нём вы стираете записанное ранее значение для ключа `"sample_pack"` значением `null`. И тогда в `LoadPackPreferences()` в переменную  `packName` записывается значение по умолчанию - `"arb"`. Попробуйте так:

```
packName = getIntent().getStringExtra("sample_pack");  
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(packName) {
   SavePackPreferences("save_pack",packName);
} 
LoadPackPreferences();
```

Comment: Это идеально сработало,я правда думал всё будет проще,моих мозгов пока до такого решения не хватает!Огромное спасибо Вам и за ваше потраченое время!